# Using the Lambda Function with Objects and for_each loops

Tags: c++, object, lambda, foreach

I'm trying to better understand a few fundamental concepts about working with the lambda functions with a vector of objects and `std::for_each()` loops.

I'm attempting to pass the `const int` contents of `someObjectVector.end()->someObjectVectorMethod()` into `i`, but just can't find a way to make it happen.

I also want to use those iterators to set the parameters of the `std::for_each()` loop. Is this just not possible, or am I approaching this the wrong way syntactically?

```
std::for_each(someObjectVector.begin()->someObjectVectorMethod(), (someObjectVector.end()->getSomeObjectVectorData(), [&](int i)
{
    someObjectVector[0].setSomeObjectVectorDate() + i;
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what is your input and what you want as the output, possibly a code snippet which compiles? I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve just by reading the question.

Comment: `someObjectVector.end()->someObjectVectorMethod()` is invalid. `.end()` points one past the last element of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is definitely wrong.

As input, `std::for_each()` expects

- a range of elements denoted by 2 input iterators
- a unary function object that each element in that range will be passed to as the sole input parameter.

In your code, `someObjectVectorMethod()` and `getSomeObjectVectorData()` are not iterators, and your lambda doesn't accept a vector element as input.

What are you TRYING to accomplish with your code?  You probably need something more like this instead:

```
std::vector<YourObjectType> someObjectVector;
...
std::for_each(someObjectVector.begin(), someObjectVector.end(),
    [](YourObjectType &obj) {
        obj.setSomeObjectVectorData(...);
    }
);
```

Or:

```
std::vector<YourObjectType*> someObjectVector;
...
std::for_each(someObjectVector.begin(), someObjectVector.end(),
    [](YourObjectType *obj) {
        obj->setSomeObjectVectorData(...);
    }
);
```

Depending on how `someObjectVector` is actually declared in your code.

Tweak the above lambdas to suit your actual needs.